# Vagrant tries to force WinRM with windows guest when I specify ssh should be used

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtual-machine

I have a windows guest with cygwin and openssh installed, with user/password configured in the Vagrantfile. When I run vagrant up, everything works until "configuring and enabling network interfaces", at which point it barfs and complains about winrm being required for windows vagrant boxes:

```
==> default: Waiting for domain to get an IP address...
==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> default: Starting domain.
==> default: Waiting for domain to get an IP address...
==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> default: Creating shared folders metadata...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
Configuring networks on Windows requires the communicator to be
set to WinRM. To do this, add the following to your Vagrantfile:

  config.vm.communicator = "winrm"

Note that the Windows guest must be configured to accept insecure
WinRM connections, and the WinRM port must be forwarded properly from
the guest machine. This is not always done by default.
```

How can I get it to stop doing this?